# Strange output from pandas plotting along with UserWarning

Tags: python, dataframe

I'm getting this warning:

```
UserWarning: Attempting to set identical left==right results
in singular transformations; automatically expanding.
```

and this nonsensical graph:

[image: graph]

when I run the following code:

```
corr.plot(x = 'count', y = 'mean')
```

on a dataframe that looks like this:

[image: data frame]

There's clearly at least some variation in each column, so why the degenerate plot?